# Sorting order in search

Tags: magento-1.9

I’ve got an attribute that is a text field with numbers in it, such as the number of days it takes to produce the product. the product sort, but it shows products in order of 10,11,12,1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

I’m assuming this is due to a stricter sort rather than a natural sort.

Does anyone know how to switch the sorting method used for the product grid’s sort by or what file i should be looking in? I know i have to sure natsort but i do not know where to put this?

Thank you

Comment: `app/design/frontend/theme/template/catalogsearch/result.phtml` shows the search result.so there you can use your php sort function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `System/Configuration/Advanced/Developer` change the configuration scope to something more specific that `Default Config`  then in debug you can turn on `Template Path Hints` and `Add Block Names to Hints` to see the structure of the page.

If the field contains only integers have you considered replacing it with an int field?

If you can't change the type, and don't want to resort the collection after the db has sorted it for you, extend `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Collection`, override `setOrder` so that for your attribute you add `ORDER BY length(text_full_of_ints) dir, text_full_of_ints dir` to the query

Comment: resorting the collection is the most trivial and least code intrusive option imo.  But, that's just like, my opinion, man.

Comment: I think you'd have to be careful where you placed it? If the query is being LIMITed then you'll be sorting the results on the current page only, the pages themselves would be in whatever the ORDER BY clause was

Answer (score 1):

just use the php function natsort() on the array of products before you display it.

Comment: sorry for not making it clear but i was asking what file is where you display it so what file should i add the natsort() in to ?